# Can't open image C

Tags: c, image, file, fread

I'm trying to open an image and copy it's bytes into an array. But, if I try to print the array where suposedly the bytes of the image were stored only a "?" is printed. Isn't it supposed to open in rb? Heres's the code:

```
char* nomefich = "cloud.png";
FILE *fi = fopen(nomefich,"rb");
buf = malloc(size); //size represents the size of file (I used struct stat to obtain that)
fread(buf,size,1,fi);
fclose(fi);
```

Comment: you say print the array but have not shown the code

Comment: When writing binary data to the terminal your terminal won't be able to interpret all symbols, so yeah that behaviour is normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the contents of the binary file you need to write the values as hex values

e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  printf( "%2X ", buf[i] );
  if ( i != 0 && (i % 16) == 0 ) 
  {
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `(i % 0)`?.I think it is UB.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be opened for reading in binary mode -- thus the rb.  Only printable characters will print, and if you are trying to print as a string, only until you reach a binary zero '\0' character.

If you want to be sure the file read, you can print the signature characters, which you can find here http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html.  I would print these as integers.